# Tkinter pyimage does not exist error. If I call the function separately everything works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Code:**
from tkinter import *
from webbrowser import *

```
def opnbk1():
    open('https://www.goodreads.com/Harry_Potter_and_the_Sorcerer_s_Stone?ac=1&from_rank=1')

def test():
    Bk= Tk()
    bk1 = PhotoImage(file='HP.png')
    book1 = Button(Bk,image=bk1,command=opnbk1,bg='white').place(relx=0,rely=0)
    Bk.mainloop()

test()#This function call works,but inside the window root, it does not.
root=Tk()
b2 = Button(root, text='Click Me', command=test).place(relx=0.167, rely=0.9)
root.mainloop()
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Hi Siva! You should include all possible details about your problem. If you can copy/paste the full error message, it could be helpful as well. Good luck!

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2645, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: It is because you have multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `test()` or `PhotoImage(master=Bk, file='HP.png')`.

Comment: @Siva A. Your code is working.